# What determines when a FileMaker custom menu is disabled?

Tags: filemaker

I have a system that I've built that makes heavy use of custom menus in FileMaker. When I log in as full access, and install the menu set with these custom menus, they appear fine. However, when a non-full access user logs in, they're disabled. This includes most of the custom menus, but not all.

For example, I have left the File>Change Password option in and the user I'm logging in as has the permission to change their password, but the Change Password menu item is disabled.

Other disabled menus include those I've placed in the View menu to navigate to different sections of the system, such as Home, People, Companies, etc. The functionality of these items is duplicated in buttons, and they work, but the menu is disabled. The buttons are calling the exact same script with the exact same parameter.

Alternatively, the File>Close command is left in and is enabled. So both Close and Change Password are based on existing commands but one's enabled and the other isn't. I can't seem to find anything in common with the menus that are enabled vs. those that are disabled.

So, under what conditions will a custom menu item be disabled?

Thanks,
Chuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [online documentation](http://www.filemaker.com.au/help/html/fmpa_custom.23.14.html#1028713) says the following about when menus are dimmed:

> Standard FileMaker menu items are dimmed if users don’t have privileges to perform the menu command. Menus are not dimmed if you attach a script to the menu item.

That being said, I wonder if you aren't encountering dimming because of the menus being based on an existing command which they don't have access to. I would try the following:

1. Turn off your custom menu for a moment and log in as the user who doesn't have access to the Change Password option. Is it still dimmed using the default menu set? If so, it sounds like you have a permissions issue and should explore that further.
2. In the permissions 'Edit Permission Set' window take a look at the 'Available Menu Commands' option and see how that is set up. If it's not set at 'All' try changing it to 'All'
3. For the View menu, look at the custom menu items and see if you have 'Based on existing command:' selected. If the menu item is performing a script, try unchecking 'Based on existing command:' and see if that changes the dimming behavior.
4. Make certain that the user has permission to run any script which the menu calls.

Good luck!